# Prevenir que un usuario se autentique mas de una vez en otros equipos laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo una aplicación en laravel 5.4 en la que un usuario autenticado no puede estar logeado en mas de un equipo a la vez, como se podria realizar esta esta comprobación?, soy nuevo en laravel, agradezco cualquier ayuda o recomendación.

Comment: comprueba en la base de datos si el usuario ya ha iniciado sesión...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938186/laravel-only-allowing-one-session-per-user-at-a-time/36350394#36350394 Prueba con esto

Answer (score 0):

yo lo que hago en mis aplicaciones, es poner un campo en la tabla usuarios donde guardo una variable al momento de que inicia sesión el usuario, esa misma variable la almaceno en $_SESSION.
despues lo que hago es consultar en la base de datos si concide con la variable session mantengo abierta la sesion del usuario, si entra desde otro navegador, guarda una variable diferente en la base de datos y al no coincidir las variables, se terminara la sesión del primer navegador... No sé si me explique xd